# Haskell - save unicode (String, characters) to file

Tags: haskell, unicode, utf-8, unicode-string

environment: windows 7 64, ghci 7.8.3

IN GHCI

```
\197 <-> Ć

Prelude> putStrLn "\197"
*** Exception: <stdout>: hPutChar: invalid argument (invalid character)
```

Finally

I try use `writeFile` function to save `String` to file;

```
writeFile "filename.txt" "ćĆ"
-- content in "filename.txt" -> †Ź
```

how to write to character quotation mark (")

```
content2 = "\"http:\\www.google.com\""
writeFile "filename2.txt content2
```

- how to store in file `content2` without Escaping character
- because I want to store something like `href="http:\\www.google.com"`

If this is wrong way, how to download webpage (html) and save it on hdd and then open it in web browser,

Comment: If I recall correctly, you need to change the codepage. This is a windows specific problem.

Comment: main problem is with "sepcial character" like 'ć', writeFile function throw exception

Comment: what do you mean by codepage? how to change codepage?

Comment: Try running `chcp 65001` in the terminal before your Haskell application.

Comment: what does the command `chcp` report? (more info on chcp: http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html )

Comment: THANKS chcp helps; I use (answer with bat file, http://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8)

Answer (score 1):

By default, a newly created handle is affected the locale encoding the OS reported (see `System.IO.localeEncoding`). In Windows that may be a very old codepage... So one way is to change the codepage to 65001 (with `chcp 65001`) prior to launching the Haskell executable. If that is unsatisfactory, you can change the encoding of any Handle in your code with `System.IO.hSetEncoding` (even stdout) or even use ByteString IO (binary) and do the encoding/decoding yourself (probably overkill if you don't need very precise control over it). Note that this means that writeFile can't be used since you don't see the handle, you'll have to write your own variant :

```
writeFileWithEncoding fp content enc =
  withFile fp WriteMode $ \h -> do
    hSetEncoding h enc
    hPutStr h content
```

Or just a version specialized for utf8.

Comment: cp 65001 isn't exactly UTF8: it's a non-unicode encoding that uses the same packing scheme (or if it is UTF8 then that means the console font associated with it has very few correct glyphs).

Comment: See the doc for System.IO for available encodings: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#g:23